# Distinguish between facebook app iframe and genuine site visit (django app)

Tags: django, facebook

I'm trying to distinguish between a web request coming from inside the iframe of my app in facebook vs a regular web visit. That way I can deliver the correct layout.

I had set a session variable when the first iframe request comes into my server (facebook sends a POST param called `signed_request` to your default canvas url),  but then if the user actually visits me website after (outside of facebook) they get iframe layout delivered instead of what my site should look like.

I've looked through all the META info that come in with the iframe request and I dont see anything that would allow me to distinguish the two.

Any help would be much appreciated.

UPDATE: I'm using AppEngine as my application host

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to make a unique url for access from Facebook, e.g. if your website is www.site.com then set up either fb.site.com or www.site.com/fb on your server and point it to the same place as www.site.com (and of course set your Facebook app settings to use the alternate url). Then your server code can easily check the accessing url to determine whether to format for Facebook or standalone website.

Another approach is to combine a session variable on the server-side with some javascript on the client-side. You can set a session variable when you receive the signed_request parameter, and then check it on each page load. As long as the session variable is set, you output iframe format and add a bit of javascript code to each page. The javascript checks to make sure the page is still in an iframe using something like `if (window.self!=window.top) { //inside iframe }`. If not inside an iframe it means the session variable is now stale, so the js jumps to some url that tells the server to clear it and then re-display the page in regular layout.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm using appengine as my host, and in order to provide https support, you need to use the subdomain they provide you (ie myapp.appspot.com )  so until they provide naked https support, this solution will not work (for me at least)

Comment: I'm not really familiar with appengine, but can you not make a subdirectory? Like myapp.appspot.com/fb?

Comment: Sure, but all i would like to do is see if the request is coming from the facebook iframe, and if so include a stylesheet that renders the page layout a little different (besides layout, all urls stay the same). It would be one thing to change the domain (and I liked that solution til i thought of the https issue), but to change the path of the application itself has all sorts of side effects

Comment: Unfortunately if you want to make the check on each request, you must make a distinct url (although that could be adding a parameter instead of a subdirectory if that is easier). If you can make all your links relative to the current path it can be almost automatic. Otherwise you might use the `<base>` tag, or define a variable that would be set to either "/" or "/fb/" and use that in all your links. An alternative would be to combine the session approach with some javascript on each page that checked if you were still in an iframe and jumped to a "session clearing" page if not.

Comment: I guess that would be me question then,  how can i check if I am in an iframe?

Comment: In javascript it's easy, something like `if (window.self!=window.top) { //inside iframe }`. But that can only be done on the client side after the page has already loaded, so you still need something "creative" on the server side. What I meant was you could set a session variable if you received signed_request, and as long as that variable is set you output iframe format and add a bit of javascript code to each page. The js checks to make sure the page is still in an iframe, and if not it means the session variable is now stale so it jumps to some url that tells the server to clear it.

Comment: BTW - checking if in a iframe and doing a redirect that resets the session to a non-frame layout worked,  if you add that you tor answer I will accept it